# Unknown IP cam clients have suddenly appeared on my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

An unknown client has oddly appeared on my Asus router:

- Cisco03533
- IP: `192.168.1.196`
- MAC: `18:16:C9:24:C8:1B`
- D-Link IP CAM

I do not own an IP Cam.

At random, the clients IP address changes to `192.168.1.51` or `192.168.1.12` or 192.168.1.108`.

The number of client devices change at random as well from 2-5 devices. The cam type changes too. Either D-Link or Samsung.

I have Samsung phones and TVs in the house. Looking at the bandwidth traffic on the router, this client appeared on the router three days ago.

I blocked the client’s MAC address from the router, but would like some feedback.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: A client cannot connect to a properly protected access point with the passphrase.  So is your password to your access point at least 16 characters?  If this device still connects after you have a secure password then it's a client you have connected to the access point yourself

Comment: The device might be (non-maliciously) misidentified. Guessing actual devices on a network can be difficult. Also, there are often utilities (even on mobile devices) to check the MAC(s) associated with a device (so you can manually check each one as it shows in the router).

Comment: You can identify the manufacturer of a device, or at least the manufacturer of the network interface controller for a device, from the first 6 hexadecimal digits of the [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control) address. [The MAC address you listed is used by Samsung Electronics](https://aruljohn.com/mac.php?mac=18%3A16%3AC9%3A24%3AC8%3A1B&rtype=mac).

Answer (score 3):

If you suspect foul play on the router, just reset the firmware.

As the NSA tools that have lately been leaked are known to contain software that  can take over a router, I would also look for a newer firmware version (and keep on  looking in the future).

Answer (score 1):

You have a password on your wifi, correct? It also isn't an easy password to guess as well? You could try changing your password and reconnect everything you own again. Your also positive that you have no cameras that connect through wifi? 360 cameras, security cameras or just a wifi enabled camera might pop up as well.